# How to commit form then open a modal dialog (edit form to edit form)

Tags: modal-dialog, edit-form, save

I have an edit form that I need to have commit data and then open another edit form with the same ID in a dialog.  Previously I did not have to save data so I used

```
    onclick="javascript: OpenPopUpPage('EditForm2URL.aspx?ID={@ID}');"
```

Since I now have to save and then open the dialog I'm trying to use....

```
    onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit')};OpenPopUpPage('EditForm2URL.aspx?ID={@ID}');"
```

When I do this the page saves then opens the dialog but refreshes and kicks the user out of the dialog before they can use it.  Any way around this?

Comment: You are open the same EditForm with same ID twice?

Comment: A different custom edit form.  Basically the user enters a large amount of information, saves, then goes to the second edit form for a few additional fields.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like form chaining. There is a function for that in the [SPServices libary](https://spservices.codeplex.com).

**[$().SPServices.SPRedirectWithID](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPRedirectWithID)**

> This function allows you to redirect to a another page from a new item
>   form with the new item's ID. This allows chaining of forms from item
>   creation onward.

This will require you to include jQuery and the SPServices library though.

**Example code**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $().SPServices.SPRedirectWithID({   
            redirectUrl: "EditForm.aspx",
            qsParamName: "OrderID"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Code taken from SPServices SPRedirectWithID page.